# Inline Interpolation of Single Quoted String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, quotes, string-interpolation

I am building a string that will be used as a command run on a Windows box over SSH.

The command must be executed with elements of it wrapped in double quotes, so I have to wrap the command as a whole in single quotes. However this means I lose the ability to use inline interpolation.

So Is there a way I can still use inline interpolation on a single-quoted string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use %Q{command} as follows:

```
 puts %Q{Hello "xyz"}  => Hello "xyz"

 puts %Q{"Hello" 'xyz'} => "Hello" 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use interpolation with single-quoted string. You can, instead, escape double quotes.

```
puts "I say \"Hello\""
# >> I say "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts %Q(I say "Hello", you say #{goodbye})
```